# Eclipse, JPA 2.0 metamodel generator and Spring Roo working together

Tags: eclipse, jpa, spring-roo, metamodel

Is there a way to put Spring Roo and [JPA 2.0 metamodel generator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpamodelgen/1.0/reference/en-US/html_single/) to work together?

I have a Spring Roo project and use Eclipse as IDE. I was able to configure the Eclipse project and maven pom.xml to use JPA 2.0 metamodel generator in the build/compile process. The problem is, the generator doesn't generate metamodel classes for Roo entities (that is, domain classes that are annotatted with `@Roo*` annotations).

I created an entity "by hand" and confirmed that the generator is properly configured. I suspect that the generator fail for Roo entities because it doesn't understand AspectJ IDT classes. Is there a way to make the generator work for Roo entities?

Oh, before I forget, these are my configurations:

- STS 2.5.1
- Spring Roo 1.1.0
- Project configuration:

  - Annotation processing enabled
  - Factory path contains `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar` and `hibernate-jpamodelgen-1.1.0.Final.jar`
- pom.xml

  - Included http://maven-annotation-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mavenrepo as a plugin repository
  - Added `org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:1.1.0.Final` as dependency
  - Added and configured `org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.5` to include `src/generated/java` as a maven source folder
  - Added and configured `org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin` to run `org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor` and place the generated code at `src/generated/java`

I can give further details if necessary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: were you able to get this working? I have a very similar setup to you and want to use JPA metamodel but have not had any success generating the entities.

Comment: @Wally, just declare the @Entity annotation on your model classes. When you do it the declaration is removed from the corresponding *_Roo_Entity.aj files and the annotation processor is able to find your entity classes. I didn't try this setup with jpamodelgen because I found Querydsl before solving the problem. Querydsl has a similar processor to generated meta models based on classes annotated with @Entity and it worked well (the only difference is that the processor is hooked into a Maven build).

Comment: @matheus.emm I'm trying to get my pom.xml properly configured for Roo and Querydsl.  Do you have a sample you can provide for that config that works in Eclipse?

Answer (score -1):

You should probably take a look at model2roo project.

http://code.google.com/p/model2roo/